# Delete Messages app

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I have downloaded an app for Messages, and I'm wondering how to delete it.
I don't see it on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an app that's ONLY for Messages (meaning there's no supporting app that is accessible from outside Messages), you uninstall it by going into Messages, taping the A application icon, tapping the four bubbles in the bottom left corner, then swiping through pages until you find it. Press and hold on the app's icon and an X will appear. Tap the X to uninstall it.

If it's part of a larger iPhone app, for example a game that includes stickers, you would delete it by deleting the iPhone app itself.

Comment: thank you but I don't understand what you mean by "the A application icon" ?

Comment: See screenshot: http://imgur.com/bUlwrqv